# Reverse a substring of a given string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to reverse a substring in Python?

For example I have the string `abcd`. I want to reverse the string from position 2 to 4. So answer will be `adcb`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generic solution:

Consider that the string contains 3 parts: prefix, the part you want to reverse and suffix. Using Python notation, that means

```
s = "abcde"

s[:1] # prefix
s[1:4] # part to be reversed
s[4:] # suffix
```

Therefore, in order to reverse a substring in a string, you want to define
the substring by left and right boundary, called lb and rb. Resulting string would therefore look like

```
s = "abcde"
result = s[:lb] + s[lb:rb][::-1] + s[rb:]
```

Left or right boundary can be omitted if the substring contains either left or right end.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of slicing:

```
s = "abcd"
print(s[0] + s[:0:-1])
```

Output:

```
adcb
```

Longer:

```
s = "abcdefgh"
print(s[0] + s[:0:-1])
```

Output:

```
ahgfedcb
```